# Displaying all the rows from different columns into one single row and single column in sql

Tags: sql, .net

I have a table in a database which consists of name, maths, science, history as the columns wherein the each persons marks are displayed of each subject.
I need to write a query wherein i need to display  everything in one single row as:
Anthony:30,70,60 $ Raghav:25,30,45 and so on..
Can anyone tell me how can i do that?

Comment: Please make this more clear by adding example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @result Varchar(max) 
SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result + '$','')+[name] + ':' + cast(maths as varchar(3)) + ',' + cast(science as varchar(3))  + ',' + cast(history as varchar(3))  
FROM tableName
```

@result variable now contains concatenated string which you can return by

```
SELECT @result
```

Comment: Can you tell me how will i view the output?

Comment: The first select statement sets value and after that SELECT @result gives the result

Comment: @m hasan: Can you please tell me how can i get the same result using a while loop?